# Android, SherlockActionBar: change text color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to change the color of text in my actionBar (from black to white), but it seems like nothing's working... somebody has suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use custom `style` (If you are using `Actionbarsherlock`)

```
    <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
         <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
         <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">17dip</item>
    </style>
```

in the `themes.xml` file.

**Edit**

to apply the theme

```
 <style name="Theme.Custom" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
 </style>
```

and in your `activity/application` in `manifest`

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way to style the action bar is using the action bar style generator online tool, you can find it here: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator .

It will take care of generating all the needed assets and styles.

To have the text white, you can simply select "Dark" or "Light - Dark Actionbar" as base theme, then change the other colors according to your needs.